# How do I format numbers to add space on thousandth and none on ten thousandth etc

Tags: php, html, css

Let me show that in an example:

What it is:

```
$ 100,000
$ 10,000
$ 1,000
```

What I want:

```
$ 100,000
$  10,000
$   1,000
```

Also I wasn't sure how to name the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends on the output context... for HTML/CSS Rana has presented a viable solution. For text-only output, `str_pad()` and a monospace font should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like in below snippet.

Define a `width` and `text-align` to the right

```css
.rich {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<span>$</span><span class="rich">100,000</span><br>
<span>$</span><span class="rich">1,000</span><br>
<span>$</span><span class="rich">100</span><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a function you can pass the number to and have the desired value, should u need to pass dynamic variables

```php
<?php

function formatNumber($number)
{
    //check string length if it;s not a multiple of three, make it the nearest multiple of three
    $pad =  (floor(strlen(number_format($number)) / 3) * 3) + 3;
    $formatted = (strlen($number % 3)) === 0 ?  number_format($number) : str_pad(number_format($number), $pad, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    //echo $formatted . "<br>" . strlen($formatted);
    echo $formatted;
}

formatNumber(127980);
```